# Text align not working in databound DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a datagridview in a C# windows form that is bound to a SQL Server Database and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to right-align the cell text.

I have set ALL the cellstyle alignment properties to middle-right, turned off sorting, and everything else that’s mentioned on stackoverflow that I could find.

I am assuming the issue is that the columns are all added on Form_Load when the DataGridView binds to the database, and that overwrites some of the alignment properties, but I can’t even change the cellstyle.alignment properties AFTER binding or even well after the form loads with a button or something.

The form user basically just adds rows to the DataGridView and Database in real time based on data readings from a USB instrument, and I’m using a bindingsource cause that’s the first thing I tried that updated the DataGridView after the INSERT command using DataAdapter. The data binding is set up essentially like this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

I also tried this example which does not use a bindingsource, and sets the cell alignment property after binding, but the alignment change did NOT work:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-formatting.htm

I feel like I’m missing something here. After writing a fairly complex (for me) desktop app, it’s been pretty frustrating to not be able to figure out how to align the bleeping text in a basic control.

Comment: You need to format the DGV : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.alignment?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&force_isolation=true

Comment: DataGridView is a class. It is part of some library/framework for building GUIs. There are multiple such libraries. We do not know which one you are using. State which library you are using.

Comment: My bad. It's just the standard DataGridView class from System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: @jdweng I did that. I set ALL of the CellStyle.Alignment properties so it's not an inheritance issue. All of the other formatting properties I set work fine when the columns generate, like color, font, etc.

Comment: Maybe text needs to be trimmer to remove white spaces at beginning and end.  Numbers may be right aligned and strings left aligned.

Comment: @jdweng I tried that too, but that could still be a source of the problem. All of the data getting added to the database is trimmed, but it almost seems like the SQL database itself is adding whitespace, which ends up showing in the bound datagridview. I have no idea how to get around that, if that is actually the problem. When I look at the SQL data in MSSMS it is all left aligned and looks exactly like it shows up in the DataGridView, and when I select a cell in the DataGridView I can delete the trailing whitespace and the text ends up right aligned.

Comment: @jdweng I fixed it. My test database had the datatypes set to nchar instead of varchar. Thanks for leading me to the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: My SQL database had the wrong datatypes in the columns. The datatypes were set to nchar so it was adding a set amount of whitespace to each string input. I switched it to varchar and it solved the problem.